# AudioKit buffer consuming a lot of ram

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

Opening a file or copying it makes buffer explode in size.

```
tape1.write(from: tape2.pcmBuffer)
```

The same thing happens after saving file and then opening it again (after composing i.e.)

```
AKAudioFile(forReading: url, commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, interleaved: true)
```

That takes a lot of memory as well, 15min recording is ~300mb ram and iPhone 5s can not handle it.
Is there a way to do it better? How to reduce buffer size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To copy a file you should use [FileManager.copyItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1412957-copyitem) `FileManager.default.copyItem(at: src, to: dst)`.  You could also create two file players from the same URL without issue, if that is your intent.

AKAudioFile doesn't read into a buffer on instantiation, so the memory use is elsewhere.  AKAudioFile.floatChannelData and AKAudioFile.pcmBuffer will read the entire file into buffer, as will creating an AKAudioPlayer from the file.

If you are playing long files, you should try [AKClipPlayer](http://audiokit.io/docs/Classes/AKClipPlayer.html).  It streams the file from disk so memory use stays low.

```
let clip = AKFileClip(url: url)
let clipPlayer = AKClipPlayer(clips: [clip])
```

Comment: thank you, i'll check AKClip player, i have tracked that indeed player init and reload was causing a problem